# Поиск ноды по шаблону названия класса в HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

На страницах есть class="result-**123456**-default", но цифры могут быть любые. Можно ли найти блок не зная цифр? Я пробовала изменить на звездочку на это не сработало

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//div[contains(@сlass,'result-*-default')])").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не смотрите только на один объект, а смотрите на картинку в целом.

К примеру, если у нас такая разметка:

```
<div class="SomeClass">
    <div class="result-123456-default">Привет мир!</div>
</div>
```

То для достижения нужной целим нам потребуется взять лишь `SomeClass`, а из него уже вытянуть первую вложенную, без разницы какой класс у нее, получим тогда:

```
//div[@class='SomeClass']/div
```

Если объектов много, то XPath будет аналогичным, метод только измениться на `SelectNodes()`.

А если таких объектов много, но есть некоторые, которые не стоит брать?

```
<div class="SomeClass">
    <div class="result-123456-default">Новость 1</div>
    <div class="result-123457-default">Новость 2</div>
    <div class="adv">Реклама</div>
</div>
```

В таком случае мы можем сразу указать в XPath какой класс нам не нужен:

```
//div[@class='SomeClass']/div[@class != 'adv']
```

либо пойти от обратного и указать только тот класс, который начинается с определенного названия:

```
//div[@class='SomeClass']/div[starts-with(@class, 'result')]
```

Как видите, не всегда требуется полное название, достаточно лишь части, либо вовсе прыгнуть на ноду выше. Ну а если всё же надо `result-*-default`, то комбинируйте несколько условий в одно, например `starts-with` и `contains` (увы, в .NET старый XPath и в нем нету [`ends-with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470779/6808809)), получите тогда нечто такое:

```
//div[starts-with(@class, 'result') and contains(@class, '-default')]
```

Либо можете написать свой собственный функционал XPath, который будет принимать например [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060199/6808809). В любом случае, все зависит от задачи и очень редко когда надо сопоставлять и начало и конец.